# What you need to say gets stepped on everyday

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix lets you drop without delay.
- My infix forms what you need to say.
- My suffix gives equality in every way.
- My whole gets stepped on everyday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a:

> **SLIPPER**

*My prefix lets you drop without delay.*

> If you **SLIP**, you fall to the ground very quickly!

*My infix forms what you need to say.*

> Your **LIP** (in fact, two of them together) helps you shape words with your mouth.

*My suffix gives equality in every way.*

> The definition of **PER** is 'for each' (or 'for every'), which might appear to be a definition of '*equality*' also.

*My whole gets stepped on everyday.*

> As a **SLIPPER** your very role is to be stepped on (or in!) to keep somebody's foot warm!